# return largerst line from 2D array

Tags: c

I need help with a function that finds the line with the largest number of numbers in a two-dimensional array and prints index this row. I don't know how to start for help thank you.

main.c

```
int array[2][2]=  { {1,0}, {0,-3} };
printf("%d\n", largest_line(2, array));
```

```
int largest_line(const int size, int array[][size]){

for(int col= 0; col < size; col++){
    for(int row = 0; row <size; row++){
     // and on this place I stop 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Define *largest number of numbers*. What should the output be in your example?

Comment: so it looks at all the rows in the field and returns the row with the largest sum of numbers in one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
int largest_line(const int size, int array[][size]){

    int largest_number = 0;
    int largest_row = 0;

    for(int col= 0; col < size; col++){
        for(int row = 0; row <size; row++){
            if(largest_number > array[col][row]) {
                largest_number = array[col][row]);
                largest_row = row;
            }
        }
    }
    return largest_row;
}
```

Comment: The algorithm used here is that we store the forward line in the variable and compare it with the current

Comment: This algorithm searches for the highest variable and saves the current row of it. Of course this is an example, you could also go for the column, if you change this code a bit.